# Strange re-render/re-paint issue in Safari when clicking out of a sub nav

Tags: html, css, safari

I have this strange issue in Safari where by clicking out of the side navigation leaves a ghost image outline of the navigation container (see screenshot)

Has anyone seen this before and does anyone know a way around it or more importantly what causes it?

It seems to only happen on 3 pages which leads me to believe it's something in those particular pages, but I'm not sure what

Any help appreciated

https://ibb.co/095BYp5

Comment: Can you please confirm that there is no CSS involving in style of this navigation?

Comment: most likely box-shadow effect, do check the click events and the child, parent elements, which has the box-shadow, or display property, and visibility property of the same.

Comment: @ibnelaiq Yes there is CSS to style the pop up, see screen shot below

https://ibb.co/bH1D7WS

Comment: @LeeD.. I think that there is an error of CSS in that some CSS properties doesn't work in safari instead of it please check "http://www.westciv.com/iphonetests/"...Or use '-webkit-' in front of your CSS3 properties.